# TCP recive window size on three-way handshake

Tags: tcp, handshake

I have a question regarding TCP receive window size.
Here is a example from the application Wireshark:

```
client A :syn, win=8192 , ws=4 ====>
<===== client B: syn, ack  win 5840 , ws=128
client A : Ack win=65700 ,
```

How did we obtain 65700 (from 8192 to 65700) in the three way handshake ?
And how does the `ws` get negotiated?

Answer (score 1):

The TCP receive Window size is not negotiated. It's just send to the other host. Each host uses it's own receive window size so the other host knows when to expect an ACK.

```
client A : >>Ack<< win=65700 , // just the confirmation
```

Comment: But why the receive window size increasing during the three way handshake , from 8192 to 65700 ? how 65700 was calculated ?

Comment: You can't tell from your ouput WHY this happened. Just that it happened. My wild guess is this: Window Size Value(16425) * Window Scaling Factor(4) = 65700

Comment: How did you get 16425 ?

Comment: 65700 / 4 :-) And on top 16425 is a common used value.

Comment: But it is not always 65700 , i have another example whree rw=66364B (16591*4) !